# Network policy not working with kuberntes and oracle connection

Tags: kubernetes

Defined a network policy for my spring boot app
Egreess allowed ip of the oracle database and applied the network policy to the container but connection keeps failing?
Any help appreciated..

Comment: Not nearly enough information provided.

Comment: Alex, it was due to a missing ip in the policy. Btw what information more was required here?

Answer (score 0):

NetworkPolicy object requires CNI. Be sure that you have one and enforce default deny all traffic. If you haven't you can start here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Comment: Yeps thanx i figured out was missing an ip as ip redirection was truned on the oracle host so had to add all the ips.